# web api / date format per request

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, globalization

Is there any way I can set up my web api, to forever serialize according to stipulated culture in the thread / by request?

If I keep in WebApiConfig / Register it picks up only once.
 I imagine that the correct thing by Request.

```
// MyCulture can be en-US and pt-BR
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo (myCulture);
```

The line above solves the problem, but is not by Request.

The question is due to the system problem to accept English (mm/dd/yyyy) and Portuguese (dd/mm/yyyy).

The call comes via angularjs and if the client (javascript) are in different format, to fall into the server, the date 05/10/2015 may turn 05/10/2015.

thank you.

Comment: Have you set the `<globalization culture="auto" uiCulture="auto" />`? By doing this the system will set the culture of the current thread automaticaly by checking the incoming request.